# Audio filtering circuit with capacitor shorted

Tags: audio, modem, filtering

I was looking at the [Adafruit FONA cellular network modem breakout board schematic](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-FONA-SIMCOM-3G-Breakout-PCB) and found something that I can't quite understand. The breakout board has an audio input and output that both goes into the SIM5320A modem through a filter.

I found the audio filter quite strange as there is 2 capacitors where both terminals are connected together. See circled components

What is the purpose of such design?

[image]

Comment: Is there a materials list that calls out the actual part numbers for these capacitors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice the designators are C14A, C14B, C14C, etc.

This likely indicates these capacitors are all part of a single capacitor array component. If the array the designer selected has too many individual capacitors than are actually needed, then shorting the unused ones avoids the possibility of static charge building up on them.

If you look at the physical layout it's likely you'll see the traces are arranged to make it easy to use cuts and jumps to re-connect those capacitors to the circuit.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I missed that.